# How to reference a user control in its own code behind?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

Let's say I have a user control with a couple of buttons. I'd like to know which one caused the postback, using this method:

```
public static Control GetPostBackControl(Page page)
    {
        Control control = null;

        string ctrlname = page.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET");
        if (ctrlname != null && ctrlname != string.Empty)
        {
            control = page.FindControl(ctrlname);
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (string ctl in page.Request.Form)
            {
                Control c = page.FindControl(ctl);
                if (c is System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button)
                {
                    control = c;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return control;
    }
```

And this is how I am calling it:

```
string btn = GetPostBackControl(this.Page).ID;
```

I'm getting the "**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**" I know now that the problem comes from the fact that I'm using **this.Page**, which represents **the parent page**.

How to reference the user control that I'm in? (not the parent page) So that it can work with the method to find the button that caused the postback?

Thanks for helping.

## EDIT

Both buttons are located inside the user control. **GetPostBackControl()** is also in the code-behind of the user control.

Comment: From what I've seen the __EVENTTARGET has the full control ID so maybe like masterPage_ChildPage_UserControlParent_YourUserControl_ElementId. But when you do FindControl you just have to pass in Element1 to get a control back

Comment: Can you write some code for that?

Comment: In the middle of some other stuff right now, but if my memory is right, you might be able split on underscore possibly and search for the last array element. Try to step in the debugger and see what's in __EventTarget. If you don't have this figured out by the time I head home I'll try to work up a demo

Comment: Before I even step into any code, I need to be able to know which argument GetPostBackControl() method should take. This method is not in the parent page code behind, but rather in the user control code behind itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a quick example on your given code and it **worked out pretty fine**. Perhaps you did **miss checking for** `Page.IsPostBack`? Obviously there will only be a postBackControl if there is a postBack...

*@Buttons* - they will be rendered as `<input type="submit">` so they won't appear within `___EVENTTARGET`. That's why **Ryan Farlay** wrote in [his blog](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2005/03/11/1886.aspx)

> However, you can still get to it, just in a different way. Since the
>   button (or input) is what causes the form to submit, it is added to
>   the items in the Form collection, along with all the other values from
>   the submitted form. [...] If you were to
>   look in the Form collection for anything that is a button then that
>   will be what caused the postback (assuming that it was a button that
>   caused the page to submit). If you **first check the __EVENTTARGET**, then
>   **if that is blank look for a button** in the Form collection then you
>   will **find what caused the postback**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        Control postBackControl = GetPostBackControl(this.Page);
        Debug.WriteLine("PostBackControl is: " + postBackControl.ID);
    }
}
public static Control GetPostBackControl(Page page)
{
    Control control = null;

    string ctrlname = page.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET");
    if (ctrlname != null && ctrlname != string.Empty)
    {
        control = page.FindControl(ctrlname);
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (string ctl in page.Request.Form)
        {
            Control c = page.FindControl(ctl);
            if (c is System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button)
            {
                control = c;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return control;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This question is part of a bigger issue that I have with a control that's I'm not able to read in the code behind. An when the page postback, the control doesn't keep it's value. For that, I'll just post a new question.